# What happens to a thread calling pthread_cond_signal?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

When a thread calls `pthread_cond_signal`, one of the threads waiting on the condition will resume its execution. But what happens to the calling thread? Does it waits for the called thread to release the mutex and then it resumes?

For example, the waiting thread:

```c
pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
// ...
pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mut);
// ...
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
```

And the signaling thread:

```c
pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
// ...
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
// ... has work to finish
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
```

In this case, how can the signaling thread continue its work if the waiting thread has taken over the mutex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread that calls `pthread_cond_signal` returns immediately. It does not wait for the woken thread (if there is one) to do anything.

If you call `pthread_cond_signal` while holding the mutex that the blocked thread is using with `pthread_cond_wait`, then the blocked thread will potentially wake from the condition variable wait, then immediately block waiting for the mutex to be acquired, since the signalling thread still holds the lock.

For the best performance, you should unlock the mutex prior to calling `pthread_cond_signal`.

Also, `pthread_cond_wait` may return even though no thread has signalled the condition variable. This is called a "spurious wake". You typically need to use `pthread_cond_wait` in a loop:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
while(!ready){
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mut);
}
// do stuff
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
```

The signalling thread then sets the flag before signalling:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
ready=1
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
```

Comment: It should be noted that if fair/FIFO queueing of waiters is required, then the mutex must be locked when calling `pthread_cond_signal`. Otherwise another thread can jump the waiters queue after the mutex has been unlocked.

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me why unlocking the mutex before signaling should be expected to provide any performance improvement.  Supposing that the signaling thread initially has the mutex locked, it must both signal the CV and unlock the mutex before the waiting thread can proceed. Why would the order of those two actions have performance implications?

Comment: If it signals first, and the waiting thread wakes quickly then the waiting thread now has to block on the mutex, which may be a kernel call, and thus slow. If the signalling thread unlocks the mutex first, then when it signals the condition variable, the waiting thread can potentially acquire the mutex immediately without blocking, and thus avoiding a kernel call.

Comment: In "Programming with POSIX Threads" David R. Butenhof writes that some operating systems implement "wait morphing": upon `pthread_cond_signal` a waiter thread is not woken up immediately by rather moved into the associated mutex wait queue (provided that the mutex is locked, I suppose). I looked for that in Linux sources, but couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: Yes, that's a possible optimization an OS might perform.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Linux has `FUTEX_REQUEUE` to perform this, but it is not used due to high complexity of a typical cond-var implementation that has to provide lots of silly guarantees. For example `pthread_cond_t` usually has another mutex within it just to support signalling outside of critical section and older implementations of glibc used `FUTEX_REQUEUE` to move thread from cond-var to an internal mutex unlocking queue.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin It hardly matters if you are signalling outside or inside cs, because thread can still wake and suspend itself immediately within intenral cond-var mutex. If you forbid calling signal from outside critical section (you will get essentially a _monitor_), you can implement requeuing with `FUTEX_REQUEUE` quite easily, although there still will be some issues that make such implementation questionable. If you emulate futex in user space, it becomes much easier. See ParkingLot as an example of futex-like user space facility (although has no requeuing).

Comment: @StaceyGirl `FUTEX_REQUEUE` would be ideal for signalling inside CS. Otherwise, the worst case scenario for a waiter blocked on a condvar futex in the kernel is to get scheduled onto a CPU, leave the kernel, block on the CS mutex, enter the kernel again to block on the CS futex only to be woken up again almost immediately when the CS mutex is unlocked. [There is a comment in glibc from 2003 "try `FUTEX_REQUEUE`", but I don't see any usage of `FUTEX_REQUEUE`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=FUTEX_REQUEUE).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I don't remember if I saw it in the library itself or in some experimental implementation, but I recall `FUTEX_REQUEUE` or `FUTEX_CMP_REQUEUE` being there. But I don't expect it to be used nowadays -  there is plenty of time for waking thread to return and unlock both mutexes before waiter return. And POSIX CVs implementation with `FUTEX_REQUEUE` (esp. for shared ones) will probably be so complex it might be faster to just awake threads early. Monitors seems to be better at this because there is no need for a mutex within a CV anymore (CS already protects monitor's CV).

Comment: This answer doesn't seem right for me. Some examples in documentation suppose opposite (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cond_destroy.3p.html), first you signal and then unlock. I'm leaning towards this usage.
But what will happen if signaling thread reach `unlock` on the same mutex first? As I understood, the behavior in that case is unknown.

Comment: The example at that man page is very specifically about ensuring that no threads are inside `pthread_cond_wait` when `pthread_cond_destroy` is called. If you unlock first, then signal, the call to `pthread_cond_broadcast` might find some of the waiters already processing a spurious wake, and thus liable to return to the `pthread_cond_wait` at an indeterminate future point. You would thus need to lock the mutex *again* to ensure the `pthread_cond_destroy` call was safe.